# Jupyterhub kernel died when using pyodbc

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterhub

I use the same env in Jupyterhub and in Jupyter notebook, but in Jupyterhub kernel dies on following line of code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=mydnsname',CHARSET='UTF8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to get it working.
What worked in the end, was shutting down and restarting JupyterHub:

- File > Hub Control Panel > Stop my server
- Click Stop my server again
- Click Logout top right
- Log back in in JupyterHub
- Rerun the python code to query your database.

For completeness, the code in my JupyterLab (JupyterHub) notebook was:

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pprint


user_id = "..."
pwd = '...'
con_string = "ServerName=DWHIQDB9;CommLinks=tcpip(host=somehost.somedomain.com;port=2638);Driver=SybaseIQ;UID=" + user_id + ";PWD=" + pwd
sql_query = """
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM A_CERTAIN_TABLE
"""
with pyodbc.connect(con_string, timeout=5) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(sql_query).fetchall()
pprint(result)
```

The notebook's kernel indeed dies with the message `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` and altering the above code snippet to catch any potential exceptions occurring on connection.cursor() failed.

What did work for me was running this code snippet in the python console. But I needed it to work from within a notebook to make longer, reproducible experiments.

Shutting down and restarting JupyterHub was the only thing that in the end worked. See above.